# JSTL how to concatenate values?

Tags: jsp, loops, jstl, concatenation, el

I got the following code:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${finalDisccount}">
                <p><c:out value="${tracksCD}" /> Tracks für CD${i} hochladen</p>
                <p><input id="filename_${i}" type="file" name="filename_${i}" size="50" multiple="multiple" required="required"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

The value "tracksCD" has be to concatenated with the variable i, so that something like this is created by the loop:

```
<p><c:out value="${tracksCD1}" /> Tracks für CD${i} hochladen</p>
<p><c:out value="${tracksCD2}" /> Tracks für CD${i} hochladen</p>
```

And so on.
Is there a way to combine ${tracksCD} and ${i} to get ${tracksCD1} and so on dynamically?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better solution would be to have the object that populates those arrays do it for you and simply pass it back.  JSPs with JSTL should only be responsible for rendering.  Preparing data should be done elsewhere.

Comment: Acutally the arrays are populated. The user has to put in a number in the previous step and with this loop the program generates upload inputs according to the given numbers. So I need the code to be like that in order to know how many input forms I have to generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the scope of the data, then you can just access it in the scope map `${requestScope}`, `${sessionScope}` or `${applicationScope}`. E.g. when it's in the request scope:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${finalDisccount}">
    <c:set var="tracksCDKey" value="${tracksCD}${i}" />
    <p><c:out value="${requestScope[tracksCDKey]}" /> Tracks für CD${i} hochladen</p>
    <p><input id="filename_${i}" type="file" name="filename_${i}" size="50" multiple="multiple" required="required"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

However, you've there a pretty nasty design mistake. Rather collect them in an array or a list as `${tracksCDs}` so that you can do as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${finalDisccount}">
    <p><c:out value="${tracksCDs[i - 1]}" /> Tracks für CD${i} hochladen</p>
    <p><input id="filename_${i}" type="file" name="filename_${i}" size="50" multiple="multiple" required="required"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

Or maybe if the `${finalDisccount}` happen to have the same size as the array/list:

```
<c:forEach items="${tracksCDs}" var="${tracksCD}" varStatus="loop">
    <p><c:out value="${tracksCD}" /> Tracks für CD${loop.count} hochladen</p>
    <p><input id="filename_${loop.count}" type="file" name="filename_${loop.count}" size="50" multiple="multiple" required="required"/></p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the array-idea did it and it's working like a charm now :)